# PropertiesConfiguration сохраняет в другой кодировке

Tags: java, кодировка, properties

имеет конфиг файл

```
# Уровень 
process.level=4
process.title=Загрузка
```

считываю ее, сохраняю разными способами, но для значений параметров сбивается кодировка, а для комментариев - сохраняется. в итоге получаю

```
# Уровень 
process.level=4
process.title=\u0417\u0430\u0433\u0440\u0443\u0437\u043A\u0430
```

вот как делаю

```
        PropertiesConfiguration p = new PropertiesConfiguration();

        p.load(new FileInputStream(properties), "UTF-8");

        System.out.println(p.getProperty("process.title")); // выдает Загрузка
        p.save(new File("P_.properties")); // process.title=\u0417\u0430\u0433\u0440\u0443\u0437\u043A\u0430

        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        p.save(sw);

        FileManager.writeToFile("S.properties" , sw.toString()); // process.title=\u0417\u0430\u0433\u0440\u0443\u0437\u043A\u0430

        p = new PropertiesConfiguration();
        org.apache.commons.configuration.PropertiesConfigurationLayout layout = new PropertiesConfigurationLayout(p);
        layout.load(new FileReader(properties));
        layout.save(new FileWriterWithEncoding("layoutManager.properties", Charset.forName("CP1251"))); //  // process.title=\u0417\u0430\u0433\u0440\u0443\u0437\u043A\u0430
```

подскажите, как сделать, чтобы сохранился нормально? 
проблема именно при сохранении, так как объект в мапе нормально лежит

Comment: пробовал под разными кодировками

Comment: Возможно,  IDEA сама преобразует в читаемый вид и для разработчика, и для компилятора. поэтому не видим проблему

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело в том, что такое сохранение и есть нормальное. Он сохраняет символы, которые не являются первыми 128 из набора `ASCI` при помощи их кодов. Это сделано, чтобы гарантировано не потерять символы национального алфивита, наверняка не зная кодировку, дабы в файле `.properties` она не хранится. Если это сильно мешает, то нужно писать собственные средства сериализации. Иначе никак.

IDEA действительно преобразует файлы `.properties` перед показом для удобочитаемости. При желании данную функцию можно отключить.

Comment: это я уже понял. не встречал ли следующее? 
`
    process.title=заголовок
    process.title2=очень длинное слово много много букв 
`
и при чтении не читается  `process.title2`

Comment: @senior нет, такого не встречал